# Create a new column based on the values of the column by ID

Tags: python, pandas

Please help me solve this problem. I searched online but couldn’t find the solution.

```
df

Id    Fruit
1     Apple
1     Carrot
2     Apple
3     Carrot

list = [fruit, vegetable, both]
```

The question is, how to assign for each id, if id’s fruit column contains apple or carrot the list. If id contains apple then assign ID 1 fruit, if carrot only, then vegetable, if both then both.

I tried to use str.contains by row, but it doesn’t take ID column.

Result

```
Newdf

Id    Fruit    New_col
1     Apple    Both
1     Carrot   Both
2     Apple    Fruit
3     Carrot   Vegetable
```

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `map` first , then we just using `transform` `nunqiue` finding the the position should be 'both'

```
s=df.Fruit.map({'Apple':'Fruit','Carrot':'Vegetable'})
mask=s.groupby(df.Id).transform('nunique').eq(2)
s[mask]='both'
df['New']=s
df
Out[190]: 
   Id   Fruit        New
0   1   Apple       both
1   1  Carrot       both
2   2   Apple      Fruit
3   3  Carrot  Vegetable
```